# Determining a sequence of numbers which satisfy some probability constraint

Tags: probability

I'm working on a problem in which I need to incorporate the behavior of some event happening with a probability over a time. The intuitive way to do this was to just say "at time $t$, this has probability $p$ of happening". But, since time is continuous, this doesn't make much sense.

I decided that the probability of the event happening within the next t units of time would be some monotone increasing function $p(t)$ from $0$ to $1$, and that this is independent of how much time has passed - i.e., at t=0, the probability of the event happening by t=5 is p(5), while at t=3 that probability is now p(2).

I wasn't making much progress, so I decided simulations would be handy, and this is where my question comes up:

Suppose I have the function $p$. I want to generate a random sequence of times that the event occurs at, such that the limiting distribution of gaps between event occurances approaches $p$.

I considered a few different approaches, but none of them seem to actually satisfy the problem. Any help is appreciated - and forgive me if this is a simple, well-known solution, I'm not very knowledgable with probability.

Comment: An https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Inhomogeneous_Poisson_point_process can be used for such a model, in the wiki terminology you would choose $\lambda(x)=1/p(x)$.

Comment: Are you saying the process is memoryless?  I.e. if the event is known not to have happened by time $t$ then the conditional probability it happens by time $t+s$ is $p(s)$? In your example it seems $t=3$ and $s=2$.  Then you have a Poisson process with exponentially distributed times between events and $p(t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$